# Not able to debug OpenCL kernel using CodeXL

Tags: c++, debugging, parallel-processing, opencl, codexl

I have RX580 GPU and writing an application in OpenCL. I want to step into OpenCL kernel code and debug it.

I have installed CodeXL for this purpose but when I do project settings and set a break point at the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` function. So that I can step later on into my kernel function. But my break point is not hit. Following are the settings I am doing for launching session.

[image]

You can see in еру following picture, break points are validly set.

[image]

When I start debugging, my application runs and exits but breakpoints are not hit.

I am not sure If I am missing any pre-requisite installation for CodeXL or something is wrong in project settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the release notes of CodeXL and also reply I got from AMD it is no longer possible to debug OpenCL kernel using CodeXL.